# Inform background function about variable change

Tags: bash

Lets say I have a program that looks like this

```
out="Hi"

printing(){
    while true
    do
         echo "$out"
         sleep 1s
    done
}

printing &
sleep 5s
out="Changed"
```

So the printing function runs in the background and I know it can not see the changes that are made on the outside. I would like to know what is an efficient way to tell the function something has chaged. I know you can do it with tmp files but it is to slow. And I am not really sure if background functions behave the same as normal ones running in the subshell? How would I change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linux shared memory to store your global variables there:

```
echo "True" > /dev/shm/state # will store value "True" in `state` variable in shared memory

cat /dev/shm/state # will read value from `state` variable
```

So just store your `out` variable in `/dev/shm` to make it visible for any subprocesses

Comment: Thanks a lot just a quick question of I am right this is faster than using a file and a bit slower than accessing it directly in the program?

Comment: @TenebrisNocte Should be fast as you're accessing RAM. I guess it could be slower than storing in local script variables as you need to call `echo` and `cat` to put/get value

Comment: thank you just one last thing could you also achive something like that with a fifo pipe and send through just the value?

Comment: @TenebrisNocte This approach will work as well for reading `var=$(< /dev/shm/state); echo $var`